# automatic ssh key generation

Tags: user-management, ssh-keys

In linux,
If I added a file or a directory in `/etc/skel`, when I create a user this get the file or dir in skel.

with

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I can create the ssh keys

how I can automatically create the ssh keys each time when I added a user?

Comment: mmm a problem is : how the user set the passphrase?

Answer (score 3):

man adduser under debian:

> If  the  file /usr/local/sbin/adduser.local exists, it will be
>   executed after the user account has been set up in order to do any
>   local  setup.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a wrapper script around `useradd` that runs `ssh-keygen` and anything else you need when you create an account.